# Three.js odd transparency artifact

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, rendering

I just recently started creating a 3D model for a website I am creating.. and for some reason one of the arms of the character is transparent, but only partially as in you can see inside it. As seen here:
[Transparent arm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D76Up.png) and I can't figure it out. I tried back tracking some of my code to no avail, and I tried re rendering it in blender (as it is a .obj import) and it still has the same issue. Does anyone happen to know a fix for the issue?

```
<body>

    <script src="./JS/three.js"></script>

    <script src="./JS/DDSLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="./JS/MTLLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="./JS/OBJLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="./JS/OrbitControls.js"></script>  
    <script src="./JS/Detector.js"></script>
    <script src="./JS/stats.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        var container, stats;

        var camera, scene, renderer;

        var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

        var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
        var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;


        init();
        animate();


        function init() {

            container = document.createElement( 'div' );
            document.body.appendChild( container );
             renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { 
              alpha: true,
              antialias: true
              } );
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( 200,300);
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );


            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 14, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, .3, 1000 );
            camera.position.z = 1;
            camera.position.y = 8;
            //camera.rotation.y = -90*(180/3.14159265)


            var orbit = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
              orbit.enableZoom = false;
              orbit.enablePan = false;
              orbit.autoRotate = true;
            // scene

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff );
            scene.add( ambient );

             var dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, .41);
            dirLight.position.set(100, 100, 50);
            scene.add(dirLight);


            var light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xf8f8ff, 0.25, 10000 );
            light.position.set( 0, 100,-75);
            scene.add( light );

            //var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xf8f8ff );
            //directionalLight.position.set( 0, 0, 1 ).normalize();
            //scene.add( directionalLight );

            // model

            var onProgress = function ( xhr ) {
                if ( xhr.lengthComputable ) {
                    var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
                    console.log( Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '% downloaded' );
                }
            };

            var onError = function ( xhr ) { };

            THREE.Loader.Handlers.add( /\.dds$/i, new THREE.DDSLoader() );

            var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
            mtlLoader.setBaseUrl( './Avatar/' );
            mtlLoader.setPath( './Avatar/' );
            mtlLoader.load( 'Avatar.mtl', function( materials ) {

                materials.preload();

                var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
                objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
                objLoader.setPath( './Avatar/' );
                objLoader.load( 'Avatar.obj', function ( object )
                 {
                    object.alphaTest = 0;
                    object.transparent = false;
                     object.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
                    //object.rotation.y = -25*(180/3.14159265)
                    //object.rotation.x = -35*(180/3.14159265)
                    object.position.y = 0;
                    scene.add( object );

                }, onProgress, onError );

            });

            //


            document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );

            //

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

        }

        function onWindowResize() {

            windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
            windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            //renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        }

        function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

            mouseX = ( event.clientX - windowHalfX ) / 2;
            mouseY = ( event.clientY - windowHalfY ) / 2;

        }

        //

        function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            render();

        }

        function render() {

            //camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * .005;
            //camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * .005;

            camera.lookAt( scene.position );

            renderer.render( scene, camera );

        }

    </script>
```

I'm a bit lost at this point and could really use your help! Thanks in advance. If you have any questions, or not sure about something in my code let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Face normals of the arm might be flipped backside. As you may know, if the face normal is facing backside, it will not be rendered, and only back-side will be rendered, even in 3d modeler too such as blender.

You can check normal direction in three.js using `FaceNormalsHelper` as well.

Docs for the helper:

- http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras.Helpers/FaceNormalsHelper
- http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_helpers

If normal direction were wrong, flip them in your 3d modeler app.